# Google Static map without api key gives 403(forbidden) error

Tags: javascript, typescript, jspdf, google-maps-static-api

I am creating pdf document using jspdf. 
In the document i have to display google map, so i used static google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro.
This works fine on localhost.

But on deploying the app it gives error 403(forbidden)
i also added parameter sensor=false in static map url.

**Request URL** : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=47.3857009,9.2798472&zoom=15&scale=2&format=png&size=600x400&maptype=roadMap&sensor=false&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7C47.3857009,9.2798472`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you MUST include API key in your request as a parameter. Without it you don't have an access to the Google Maps API thus `403` error code which clearly states: access is forbidden. You even provided a documentation which shows an example of the request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The last `key` parameter is required to make it working.

Comment: Indeed, an API key is mandatory since June 22, 2016: https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Comment: Yes that's true.. but surprisingly application was working few days back without API key and suddenly stopped working.. what may be the reason behind this? Can you please explain..

Comment: That's becausw they have limits